# Create once Coupon in Woocommerce via Hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, hook

I'm trying create once coupon  But by default, many coupons are produced and their production does not stop
I created a plugin to create coupons and wrote codes that I put below

```
add_action('wp_loaded' , 'create_coupon');
function create_coupon(){
    $coupon = new wc_coupon();
    $coupon->set_code('customcode'); // create coupon code
    $coupon->set_amount(300); // discount amount

    $coupon->save();
}
```

What this code does:
this code create many coupon but I need once coupon
what should i do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `wc_get_coupon_id_by_code` to check coupon code is already exist or not.

```
function create_coupon(){
    $coupon = new wc_coupon();
    if( !wc_get_coupon_id_by_code( 'customcode' ) ) {
        $coupon->set_code('customcode'); // create coupon code
        $coupon->set_amount(300); // discount amount
        $coupon->save();        
    }

}
add_action('wp_loaded' , 'create_coupon');
```